# Android/Java Firebase adding unexpected value to key/reference

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Let me start by saying that I am very new to using Firebase.

I am trying to push a custom object with a string called "mGameSessionID" to my Firebase Database using push():

```
DatabaseReference pushedPostRef = 
myRef.child(myRef.push().getKey());

String gameSessionID = pushedPostRef.getKey();

GameSession gameSession = new GameSession(gameSessionID);

pushedPostRef.setValue(gameSession);
```

However when setting the value using ".setValue(gameSession)" it adds an extra gameSessionID value to the database

[image: Example picture of what the firebase looks like]

Here is the GameSession class:

```
String mGameSessionID;

GameSession()
{

}

GameSession(String gameSessionID)
{
    mGameSessionID = gameSessionID;
}

public String getGameSessionID() 
{
    return mGameSessionID;
}

public void setGameSessionID(String gameSessionID) 
{
    mGameSessionID = gameSessionID;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase Realtime Database SDK will serialize all visible fields and JavaBean-type getter methods on an instance of an object using reflection to discover them.  So, if it sees a field "foo", it will serialize a property called "foo".  If it sees a getter method called "getFoo", it will serialize a property also called "foo".

For JavaBean type objects like your GameSession, fields with accessors (getters and setters) should be private, with access only allowed through them:

```
private String mGameSessionID
```

This should prevent the SDK from seeing `mGameSessionId`, and instead only use the visible getter method for it.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you for the clarification. Sometimes I forget that I haven't declared something private or public!